# Separate privileges for External Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to create and drop external tables and im able to do that in non production environment (its used to import massive csv files, so those tables persist only for the duration of the import). However there is no way i can have table create and drop rights on production, so im not sure how to do that on production. How are you solving such problem ?

I can see from documentation that privileges for external tables are a subset of privileges for "normal" tables, while i was hoping there could be a set of privileges for external tables only, which would solve my problem. Is there something like that in newer versions (im using 12c)

from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tables013.htm#i1007668) :

```
System and object privileges for external tables are a subset of those for regular table. Only the following system privileges are applicable to external tables:

CREATE ANY TABLE

ALTER ANY TABLE

DROP ANY TABLE

SELECT ANY TABLE
```